# Why is this parameter empty?

Tags: c#

```
public static void Connect(EndPoint remoteEP, Socket client) {
    client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, 
        new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client );

   connectDone.WaitOne();
}

private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
    try {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete the connection.
        client.EndConnect(ar);

        Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
            client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        // Signal that the connection has been made.
        connectDone.Set();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Hello, I have a question for upper two function 
In function "client.BeginConnect" , why is parameter of ConnectCallback empty?
ConnectCallback function has parameter (IAsyncResult ar). but BeginConnect doesn't call this parameter.. Who can answer my question please?

Comment: I assume that `AsyncCallback` accepts a delegate for the method to invoke once it's completed. It will call the method `ConnectCallback` and pass the `IAsyncResult` that it generated.

Comment: It's all done "Under the hood", after completing asynchronous action it calls `ConnectCallback` method and passes produced `IAsyncResult` which contains informations about this particular asynchronous operation. It also contains parameter `client` in your case which was specified as `AsyncState`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeginConnect` method expects a delegate reference to be passed as the second parameter, which will be invoked when the asynchronous task finishes. If you specified a parameter to `ConnectCallback`, it would have been evaluated as a method call instead and the result of that would be `void` (since it's a void method), so your code wouldn't compile.

In other words, if you have a method like this:

```
void DoStuff(int parameter)
{ ... }
```

Then there is a difference between getting the *reference* to the `DoStuff`:

```
// method variable will get the reference to the DoStuff method
Action<int> method = new Action<int>(DoStuff);

// invoking the delegate will invoke the actual DoStuff method
method(7);
```

and *invoking* the method (evaluating it):

```
// this will simply evaluate DoStuff
DoStuff(7);
```

Delegates passed to asynchronous methods are called "callbacks", because the asynchronous method is supposed to call them once it finishes its job. Actual parameter which is passed to the callback delegate is passed from the async method in that case, either created by the method, or supplied by yourself sometime earlier.

In case of `BeginConnect`, you also pass a `state` paramter which is the actual parameter which will be passed to your callback, meaning that `Socket.BeginConnect` does something functionally similar to this, under the hood:

```
void BeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    // create an async task and return to called immediately
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
         // do some stuff on a background thread
         ....

         // call `callback` when done, and pass the `state` parameter
         // through the `IAsyncResult` parameter
         var result = new ConnectAsyncResult(..., state, ...);
         callback(result);
    });
}
```

And the responsibility of your callback method is to call `EndInvoke` on the passed parameter to finish the operation.

This pattern enables your calling code to continue executing, and receive a notification, using all the necessary information ("state") about who actually called it.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncCallback` is a delegate that will execute the callback method which has `IAsyncResult` as its parameter. You can see the description [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback(v=vs.110).aspx). So basically you need to supply a method that accept a `IAsyncResult` as a parameter so that it can be called by the `AsyncCallback` delegate, which is in your case your `ConnectCallback` method